# Función no devuelve valor

Tags: python

Tengo esta función para leer una línea aleatoria de un archivo de texto pero no consigo que me devuelva ningún valor.

```
def get_quote():

    f = open('quotes.db','r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
    total_lines = len(f.readlines())
    line = random.randint(1, total_lines)
    it = (linea for i, linea in enumerate(f) if i >= line)

    for linea in it:
        quote = 'Quote #' + str(line) + ' ' + linea

        return quote

    f.close()
```

El archivo quotes.db es un archivo de texto plano

```
Adroc: puta manía de vender cartuchos sueltos... yo lo quiero con su caja y su puto manual
Sandra: Yo? O es que Adroc me robó la cuenta? :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye:
Sandra: Mario, desde ayer ya nos los hemos comido xD con los churros hay q ser rápidos
Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.
Adroc: a tu edad aún se felicitan los cumpleaños... a la mía ya se da el pésame xD
```

Comment: Hola @Adroc, puedes poner 5-10 lineas de ejemplo del fichero origen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### solución

```
import random

def get_quote():

    with open('quotes.db','r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    random_line_number = random.randint(1, len(lines) - 1)

    return f"Quote # {lines[random_line_number]}"
```

#### detalles

- Al tratar con ficheros es importante utilizar un [`contenxt Manager`](https://ellibrodepython.com/context-managers-python), la expresión `with xxxxx as f`  lo es. En esto ejemplo muy probablemente no lo necesitas, pero es una buena practica utilizarlos.
- Al buscar el número aleatorio (`random_line_number = random.randint(1, len(lines) - 1)`), hay que tener en cuenta que las listas empiezan por 0, por eso restamos con `-1`
- Selecciona el `encoding` adecuado.
- El retorno de la función devuelve un `f-string`. Disponible a partir de `Python 3.6`. Caso que utilizes una versión mas antigua deberás hacerlo con `str.format()`, substituye por:

  `return "Quote # {}".format(lines[random_line_number])`

#### demo

```
get_quote()
'Quote # Adroc: a tu edad aún se felicitan los cumpleaños... a la mía ya se da el pésame xD\n'
get_quote()
'Quote # Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.\n'
get_quote()
'Quote # Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.\n'
get_quote()
'Quote # Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.\n'
get_quote()
'Quote # Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.\n'
get_quote()
'Quote # Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.\n'
get_quote()
'Quote # Sandra: Mario, desde ayer ya nos los hemos comido xD con los churros hay q ser rápidos\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

En

```
total_lines = len(f.readlines())
```

`f.readlines()` lee el archivo completo y descartas su contenido. Luego de eso, no queda más que leer y por tanto, la línea

```
it = (linea for i, linea in enumerate(f) if i >= line)
```

falla.

Al calcular que línea devolver,

```
line = random.randint(1, total_lines)
```

cuentas a partir de uno, pero en Python los arreglos se cuentan a partir de cero. Además, el límite superior es `total_lines - 1`.

Aquí estas tratando de recuperar **todas** las líneas a partir del número de línea que recién calculaste. No tiene sentido, pues sólo estas interesando en **una** línea

it = (linea for i, linea in enumerate(f) if i >= line)

El ciclo `for` que viene a continuación no tiene sentido, ya que retornas en la primera iteración:

```
for linea in it:
    quote = 'Quote #' + str(line) + ' ' + linea
    return quote
```

Tampoco cierras el archivo, pues haces el `return` antes.

**Código correcto**

```
import random
def get_quote():
    f = open('quotes.db','r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
    #   Leer todas las citas al arreglo quotes.
    quotes = f.readlines()
    #   Elegir un indice al azar
    line = random.randint(0, len(quotes) - 1)
    #   Armar la cita en base al indice recién calculado
    quote = 'Quote #' + str(line) + ' ' + quotes[line]
    #   Cerrar el archivo
    f.close()
    #   Devolver la cita.
    return quote
```

**Demo**

```
print(get_quote())
```

produce:

```
Quote #3 Quimera: no, si que pasa algo, pasan muchas cosas, retale a un duelo.
```